Installing php extensions on Docker official images fails using mlocati github install-php-extensions project
I'm new to Docker. I'm trying to set up an image based on PHP+Apache for testing and development.
Since I'm migrating from an XAMPP install, I want to install all the same extensions to PHP, so I don't run into some problems in the future.
I found this script on GitHub (https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer/tree/master), which seems to do the job of installing extensions easily and its even referenced on Docker Hub official PHP page.
Here is the relevant part of my Dockerfile:
FROM php:8.2-apache

ADD https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer/releases/latest/download/install-php-extensions /usr/local/bin/

RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/install-php-extensions; \
    install-php-extensions gd gettext gmp mysqli openssl pdo pdo_dblib pdo_mysql zip

Upon trying to build my image with the following command:
docker build -t myserver:1.0 .

The process fails with the following message:
Sending build context to Docker daemon  31.88MB
Step 1/5 : FROM php:8.2-apache
 ---> 5a1ec79885c8
Step 2/5 : ADD https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer/release
s/latest/download/install-php-extensions /usr/local/bin/
Downloading  186.6kB/186.6kB

 ---> Using cache
 ---> c1aca6cded16
Step 3/5 : RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/install-php-extensions;     install-php-e
xtensions gd gettext gmp mysqli openssl pdo pdo_dblib pdo_mysql zip
 ---> Running in dc5affffd997
The script /usr/local/bin/install-php-extensions is meant to be used with offici
al Docker PHP Images - https://hub.docker.com/_/php
The command '/bin/sh -c chmod +x /usr/local/bin/install-php-extensions;     inst
all-php-extensions gd gettext gmp mysqli openssl pdo pdo_dblib pdo_mysql zip' returned a non-zero code: 1


Isn't php:8.2-apache an official PHP image? Why is it failing? What I'm not seeing here?
I didn't find any answers online neither anyone having the same problems with that Github project.
Thanks in advance
Tried to execute the script as explained on its GitHub page, without any success.

Works for me. Try re-pulling the base image.

I've already tried this multiple times. I think the problem must be on my local machine then.

As I suspected, the problem was indeed on my local machine. Did a fresh install and everything worked as intended, in case anyone reaches this question.

As I suspected, the problem was indeed on my local machine. Did a fresh install and everything worked as intended, in case anyone reaches this question.
